# Translating FEN strings to chess peices with dynamic chess board divs

Tags: javascript, chess, fen

Given a valid FEN string, I want to change the classes of certain board places to have the chess peice go in that spot. However, because it is too tedious to do myself, I am generating a chess board dynamically. I am also (currently) not worrying about the "w KQkq - 0 1" part of the string.

I want the classes within the element to change, however I expect the problem is because the elements are not fully rendered yet. This is what I am trying:

```
class Grid {
    constructor (length, height) {
        this.length = length;
        this.height = height;
    }
    render(fen) {
        let total = this.length * this.height;
        for (let i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
            const whiteSquare = document.createElement('div');
            whiteSquare.style.cssText = 'height:100px;width:100px;background-color:#ff9c9c;display:inline-block;padding:0;';
            whiteSquare.id = `${i}`;
            whiteSquare.className = 'ws';
            const blackSquare = document.createElement('div');
            blackSquare.style.cssText = 'height:100px;width:100px;background-color:#fa6666;display:inline-block;padding:0;';
            blackSquare.id = `${i}`;
            blackSquare.className = 'bs';
            const br = document.createElement('br');
            console.log(`${i}`)
            document
                .getElementById('board')
                .appendChild(i % 2 === Math.ceil(i / this.length) % 2
                    ? whiteSquare
                    : blackSquare
                );
            if (i % this.length == 0) document.getElementById('board').appendChild(br);
            fen.split('');
            let el;
            for (let i = 0; i < fen.length; i++) {
                el = document.getElementById(i);
                switch (fen[i]) {
                    case 'p':
                        el.classList.add('bpawn');
                        break;
                    case 'r':
                        el.classList.add('brook');
                        break;
                    case 'n':
                        el.classList.add('bknight');
                        break;
                    case 'b':
                        el.classList.add('bbishop');
                        break;
                    case 'q':
                        el.classList.add('bqueen');
                        break;
                    case 'k':
                        el.classList.add('bking');
                        break;
                    case 'P':
                        el.classList.add('wpawn');
                        break;
                    case 'R':
                        el.classList.add('wrook');
                        break;
                    case 'N':
                        el.classList.add('wknight');
                        break;
                    case 'B':
                        el.classList.add('wbishop');
                        break;
                    case 'Q':
                        el.classList.add('wqueen');
                        break;
                    case 'K':
                        el.classList.add('wking');
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
let board = new Grid(8, 8);
board.render('rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR')
```

This generates an error saying that classList is not defined. Is there a way to render these strings with dynamic board slots?

Comment: PLease make your question include a [mre].

Comment: Well then, I am using a class function to render HTML elements, and I then want to select those elements and change the classes of them based on a FEN string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong. First off your first `for` loop starts at `1` while the second one starts at `0`. Making the IDs inconsistent.

Furthermore you have the `for` loops nested but instead they need to be one after the other so we know all elements are added to the DOM.

I made the squares a bit smaller so they look better in the small snippet preview.

```js
class Grid {
  constructor(length, height) {
    this.length = length;
    this.height = height;
  }

  render(fen) {
    let total = this.length * this.height;

    for (let i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
      const whiteSquare = document.createElement('div');
      whiteSquare.style.cssText = 'height:50px;width:50px;background-color:#ff9c9c;display:inline-block;padding:0;';
      whiteSquare.id = `${i}`;
      whiteSquare.className = 'ws';

      const blackSquare = document.createElement('div');
      blackSquare.style.cssText = 'height:50px;width:50px;background-color:#fa6666;display:inline-block;padding:0;';
      blackSquare.id = `${i}`;
      blackSquare.className = 'bs';

      const br = document.createElement('br');

      // console.log(`${i}`)

      document
        .getElementById('board')
        .appendChild(i % 2 === Math.ceil(i / this.length) % 2 ?
          whiteSquare :
          blackSquare
        );

      if (i % this.length == 0) document.getElementById('board').appendChild(br);
    }

    fen.split('');

    let el;
    for (let i = 1; i <= fen.length; i++) {
      el = document.getElementById(i);

      switch (fen[i]) {
        case 'p':
          el.classList.add('bpawn');
          break;
        case 'r':
          el.classList.add('brook');
          break;
        case 'n':
          el.classList.add('bknight');
          break;
        case 'b':
          el.classList.add('bbishop');
          break;
        case 'q':
          el.classList.add('bqueen');
          break;
        case 'k':
          el.classList.add('bking');
          break;
        case 'P':
          el.classList.add('wpawn');
          break;
        case 'R':
          el.classList.add('wrook');
          break;
        case 'N':
          el.classList.add('wknight');
          break;
        case 'B':
          el.classList.add('wbishop');
          break;
        case 'Q':
          el.classList.add('wqueen');
          break;
        case 'K':
          el.classList.add('wking');
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}

let board = new Grid(8, 8);
board.render('rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR')
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I pasted in the for loop from a seperate function I made earlier without realizing that it was in the for loop. Thanks!